# Run command for every file in directory

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm converting all of my video files to WebM, to greatly reduce the amount of hard disk space being used. To do this I use the program "ffmpeg" which requires an input and output file specified.
Since the converting process takes a long time, I wish to run it day and night for every video file in my video folder, so I don't have to manually do it myself.

By Googling myself I found ways to do this but the output would be 1 big file.
Can anybody explain me how I convert "video1.avi" to "video1.webm", and "video2.avi" to "video2.webm", etc etc automatically?

Comment: for i in *.avi; do ffmpeg $i ${i%.avi}.webm; done

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a *bash loop* - the basic structure would be something like

```
for file in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%.avi}".webm; done
```

You can add whatever other `ffmpeg` command line options you require as appropriate.

Comment: This works great. Can I also do this recursive somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Below a python script to do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess

sourcedir = "/path/to/sourcedirectory"

for file in os.listdir(sourcedir):
    name = file[:file.rfind(".")]
    subprocess.call(["fmpeg", "-i", sourcedir+"/"+name+".avi", sourcedir+"/"+name+".webm"])
```

By using subproces.call() the script will only continue on the next conversion when the last one has finished.

**To use:**

Copy the script into an empty text file, set the source directory of your files, save it as `convert.py` and run it by the command

```
python3 /path/to/convert.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use my free application. It is called [dmMediaConverter](http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html) and it is a simple frontend for ffmpeg. For your need you must use **bulk** option then drop all files that you need converted and choose the appropriate options. The naming for output files is done automatically. Yoiu must download it from the link below since the one in Ubuntu Software Center is to old.
I hope that you like it.
http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html